# Moving document causing this error " smaller version limit than the source "

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, versioning

we want to move files from an online document library to another online document library inside the same site collection, using the "Move to" button, but i got this error:-

[image]

> ... a smaller version limit than the source

Although on the source and destination we have enabled versioning, as follow:-

1) On the source:-

[image]

2) on the destination:-

[image]

could the problem be in the number of drafts?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, drafts are versions too, I think that you need in the new library versions + 1, because it will move all version and create maybe new one, so if you want try it, set the properties the same and add + 1 to all of them.

If you dont want versions, just copy files with Explorer or sync with OneDrive Client or disable version in the source library.

Comment: thanks for your reply. ok will try to define the destination number of draft to be 101. but seems we will get this error regardless if the documents i am planning to move have more than 100 draft versions or not. because in my case i have maximum of 3-4 draft versions for each document.. what do you think ?

Comment: I think major versions 101 too.

Comment: can you write here number of versions on document which you want to move? if you create new document, so there will be only 1 major if you publish this document, it will move correctly? Try publish document, it will create major version, check major versions number.

Comment: ok fine, but i also do not have any document which have more than 100 major versions .. seems we will get this error regardless if the documents i am planning to move have more than 100 draft or major versions ??.

Comment: I tried it now, created docx document, create 2.1 version, move to another library, libraries was set like yours first, everyting works fine, maybe the migration process checking if the set of the libraries is the same. Can you try it too?

Comment: the weird thing is that the default value for minor versions is 511. so this mean the destination should allow 511, while on the source list it explicitly mention that the maximum number is 100.. but the error we get mentioned that the destination has smaller minor version compared to the source.. which is not the case as 511 can not be less than 100...

Comment: Are you able to move documents or not? So try to add 511 in all values and move them.

Comment: if i add the minor version limit to be `100`.. i can move them, but my question is about the original error i got as it does not make sense? is this correct? as on the destination i did not specify any value so it should defualt to 511 which is more than the explicit 100..

Comment: No if you dont specific a value, so the checkbutton is ton checked, so there is 0 minor versions. Second it could be, as I said, it checking the same valies before moving. If it is resolved, please mark my answer, Very Thanks :)